# Binding data into activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to bind data into my activity, so that every item will be with correct text. I was following the tutorial but, it only shows how to load the image. Iwas trying with item.getTitle().into(titleorg); but got some errors

Thats my details activity

```
public class OrgDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imgorg;
TextView titleorg, descorg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_org_details);

    this.imgorg = findViewById(R.id.item_org_logo);
    this.titleorg = findViewById(R.id.item_org_title);
    this.descorg = findViewById(R.id.item_org_description);
    Org item = (Org) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("orgObject");
    loadOrgData(item);
}

private void loadOrgData(Org item) {
    Glide.with(this).load(item.getDrawableResource()).into(imgorg);

}
```

Thats my model

```
public class Org implements Serializable {
private String title, description;
private int drawableResource;

public Org(int drawableResource) {
    this.drawableResource = drawableResource;
}

public Org(String title, String description, int drawableResource) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.drawableResource = drawableResource;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getDrawableResource() {
    return drawableResource;
}

public void setDrawableResource(int drawableResource) {
    this.drawableResource = drawableResource;
}
```

Comment: You should share the code in the question body instead of uploading pictures.

Comment: Seems like this should work (for title) : `titleorg.setText(item.getTitle())` - sets the title textview with the Org title.  (after setting `item` ofcourse in constructor - so last line).